# send multiple cURL and force the code to not wait for a response

Tags: php, api, curl

How can I stop my function from reciving responses when I send cURL requests? I developed this function based on http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php documentation. However when I try send over 50 messages the app I am developing freezes at the send button for over 20 seconds. Is there a way to send multiple cURL and force the code to not wait for a response?

```
function send_multi_data($url,$data){
//create the multiple cURL handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();
$active = null;
$count=0;

// set URL and other appropriate options
foreach($data as $message){
    $count++;
    $ch[$count] = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch[$count], CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch[$count], CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch[$count], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $message); 
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch[$count]);
}
//execute the handles
    do {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
    } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

    while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
        if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
            do {
                $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
            } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
        }
    }

// Close the handle
$count1=0;
foreach($data as $message){
    $count1++;
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch[$count1]);
}
curl_multi_close($mh);
```

}